# how to convert hex values to double float integer in python

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I have these hex values:

"28b6 b33 157b 3fd8 6791 1510 31df 3fe3 90d8 d063 40c 3fd8 e8cb 23ed 23fb bfe3 0 0 0 0 1111 2222 3333"

I unpack it to "ddddfihhh" in this struct format:

```py
import struct
data1 = "28b6 b33 157b 3fd8 6791 1510 31df 3fe3 90d8 d063 40c 3fd8 e8cb 23ed 23fb bfe3 0 0 0 0 1111 2222 3333"
data2 = data1.split()
data3 = "".join(data2)
data = struct.unpack(">ddddfihhh",bytes.fromhex(data3))
print(data)
```

I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 6, in 
> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 46 bytes

If I change my input to this format:

```
data1 = "3fd8157b0b3328b63fe331df151067913fd8040cd06390d8bfe323fb23ede8cb0000000000000000111122223333"
```

I am getting my desired output as:
"0.376311 0.599838 0.375247 -0.598142 0.000000 0 4369 8738"